# is there a better way of initializing correctly scoped variables inside if statements

Tags: scope

I'm curious to know if there is there a prettier way of correctly scoping objects that are initialised inside of if statements

say you have the following script:

```
if (x){
    create object_A
}

print(object_A)
```

the above will fail because object A is out of scope for the print so the obvious thing to do is initialise a null variable before the if statement like this:

```
variable_to_reference_object_A = null

if (x){
variable_to_reference_object_A = create object_A
}

print(variable_to_reference_object_A)
```

This just always makes me feel like a silly billy because I'm basically saying is:

`variable_to_reference_object_A = i haven't a clue because i haven't created it yet`

very curious to see what you guys have to say about this, as id love to know if I'm completely doing things wrong (and possibly why it seems to show up in almost all languages). TIA

Comment: That would probably depend on what language you were asking about, which you neglected to identify.

Comment: this occurs in many languages so i wanted to leave my question relatively general. but for argument's sake let's say java

Comment: In java you can *declare* a variable w/o specifying an initial value (although it will get a default one).